# TestNG.java.lang.NullPointerException running second @Test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

It runs first test, but then I'm getting null pointer exception when running Edit Profile test.
Not sure why.
I globally declared public driver.
Please help. Thanks

```
package test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.tapanalytics.config.Configuration;
import com.tapanalytics.pom.domain.analyticsEditProfilePage;
import com.tapanalytics.pom.domain.analyticsLandingPage;
import com.tapanalytics.pom.domain.analyticsLoginPage;

public class TestLogin {

public  WebDriver driver;// = new FirefoxDriver();
public String baseURL = "mytestsite.com";

@BeforeTest
 public void setBaseURL(){
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   driver.get(baseURL);
}

//Login test
@Test
public void testLogin() throws InterruptedException{

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    analyticsLoginPage mylogin = PageFactory.initElements(driver, analyticsLoginPage.class);
    analyticsLandingPage landingpage = mylogin.login("username", "password");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}

//Edit Profile test

@Test//(dependsOnMethods = { "testLogin" })
public void verifyProfile() throws InterruptedException{
    // driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    analyticsLandingPage landingpage = new analyticsLandingPage();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    landingpage.gotoProfile();



    //driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='left-frame']/div/div[2]/a[3]/span")).click();
    //Thread.sleep(5000);
    analyticsEditProfilePage editprofile = PageFactory.initElements(driver, analyticsEditProfilePage.class);
    editprofile.verifyEditFirstName();
    editprofile.verifyEditLastName();
    editprofile.verifyCompanyName();
    editprofile.verifyReportingProfile();
    editprofile.verifyUsageStatistics();


    }

@AfterTest
public static void quitDriver(){
    driver.quit();
}
```

PASSED: testLogin

FAILED: verifyProfile

```
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> com.tapanalytics.pom.domain.analyticsLandingPage.gotoProfile(analyticsLandingPage.java:42)
>   at test.TestLogin.verifyProfile(TestLogin.java:64)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
> org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
>   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)   at
> org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)    at
> org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)  at
> org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>   at
> org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
>   at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)    at
> org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)    at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)   at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)  at
> org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)   at
> org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:112)     at
> org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)  at
> org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:176)
```

Comment: Can you show the code from the goToProfile() method?

Answer (score 6):

There are two issues with your code.

***The first:***

It seems like you never apply the PageFactory on this class. Therefore, when trying the line `profile.click()` the variable is null (because never initialized). Hence your exception.

Solution: add the following line like you did for the other classes.

```
analyticsLandingPage landing = PageFactory.initElements(driver, analyticsLandingPage.class);
```

***The second***:

You are currently creating a new object like this:

```
analyticsLandingPage landingpage = new analyticsLandingPage();
```

However, you posted your class like this:

```
public class analyticsLandingPage 
{ 
     WebDriver driver; 

     public analyticsLandingPage(WebDriver driver){ 
          this.driver = driver; 
     } 

     @FindBy(xpath = Configuration.profile) 
     public WebElement profile; 

     public void gotoProfile(){ 
         profile.click();   
     } 
}
```

**Problem**: you are calling the default constructor of the class, in which the driver variable does not get initialized.

**Solution**: make sure you pass the parameter so you call the custom constructor.

```
analyticsLandingPage landingpage = new analyticsLandingPage(driver);
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be your driver is not initialized in `landingpage.gotoProfile();`

Check in `gotoProfile()` method if driver is initialized, properly.

**Things you can try**

1. Pass the `driver` to `gotoProfile()` method, as shown below

`landingpage.gotoProfile(driver);`

and accepting argument in gotoProfile method as bellow

```
public void gotoProfile(WebDriver driver) {
// code of go to Profile
}
```

OR

2. While creating object of `analyticsLandingPage` class pass the `driver` as argument and write a constructor which will initialize the value of `driver` in `analyticsLandingPage` class, as shown below.

Creating object

```
analyticsLandingPage landingpage = new analyticsLandingPage(driver);
```

Initialize driver value in `analyticsLandingPage` class

```
public class analyticsLandingPage {

WebDriver driver;

public analyticsLandingPage(WebDriver driver) {
this.driver = driver;
}
 // Rest of analyticsLandingPage code
}
```

Edit Profile class

```
package com.tapanalytics.pom.domain;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.tapanalytics.config.Configuration;

public class analyticsLandingPage {

          WebDriver driver;

       public analyticsLandingPage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

@FindBy(xpath = Configuration.manage_dashboard)
public WebElement manage_dashboard;

@FindBy(xpath = Configuration.manage_services)
public WebElement manage_services;

@FindBy(xpath = Configuration.profile)
public WebElement profile;

@FindBy(xpath = Configuration.support)
public WebElement support;

@FindBy(xpath = Configuration.logout)
public WebElement logout;

public void gotoMangeDashboards(){
    manage_dashboard.click();
}

public void gotoServices(){
    manage_services.click();        
}

public void gotoProfile(){
    profile.click();    
}

public void gotoSupport(){
    support.click();    
}

public void Logout(){
    logout.click(); 
}


}
```

Comment: Thanks , I tried both options and still getting same error. Here is my goto Profile class.

Comment: package com.tapanalytics.pom.domain;

public class analyticsLandingPage {
 
          WebDriver driver;
 
       public analyticsLandingPage(WebDriver driver){
  this.driver = driver;
 }
 
 @FindBy(xpath = Configuration.profile)
 public WebElement profile;
 
 public void gotoProfile(){
  profile.click(); 
 }
}

Comment: Here is copy of my testng.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suite" parallel="none">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="test.TestLogin"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

Answer (score 0):

```
public  WebDriver driver;// = new FirefoxDriver();
public String baseURL = "";

@BeforeTest
 public void setBaseURL(){
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   baseURL ="https://www.mytestsite.com";
   driver.get(baseURL);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain to the OP why your code will help. A code-only answer without any further information is not especially helpful, especially for a question as old as this one.

Answer (score -1):

try using public **static**

public static webdriver driver 
in each class files

public static is not needed if you are running a single test case, but since in a suit where parallelization may occur for multiple cases, so public ststic is needed for multiple test cases

Comment: This depends on if you want to use it as a static class or not within the suite.  Please improve your answer by explaining why this approach might help the questioner.  What are the disadvantages?